# IDEA: How to chose what is shown in Project navigator?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the example below, the only things I care for are:

- src
- pom.xml

Everything else is noise to me.

How can i reduce this noise please?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences -> File Types -> Ignore Files and Folders

Add any patterns you want the IDE to ignore.